# New Swing JLayer in Java 7

Tags: java, swing, components

I am just catching up with some of the new features in J7 and am perplexed by the addition of these **JLayers** in Swing. Since they're so new I am having tremendous difficulty finding good literature on them and the best practices of using them.

Could anybody point me in the right direction or provide an example of what these components do and what purposes they (generally) serve?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Here is an example of JLayer for creating [round buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299864/css3-to-style-java/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JLayer can be used to dynamically enhance any of your existing components.

Say you have some custom button (say MyJButton) and you want to add a mouse over effect or maybe some shading.  Traditionally you would create a new class that inherits from MyJButton that would implement your new features.

One problem with this is approach is that the new effects are only applicable to MyJButton (since your new class extends MyJButton).  Another problem with this approach is that you can't change the enhancements / effects at run time, since inheritance relations are fixed at compile time.

Using a `JLayer`, you can put a `LayerUI` together with any existing `Component` (not just a JButton or MyJButton) in order to add your custom effects to a component.  If you have a LayerUI that does shading, you can put it together with a JButton, JTextField, JPanel or any other component to perform that shading.  You can also change the composition of LayerUIs and Components at run time.

The `JLayer` is just a special case of the [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern.

http://www.intermediatejava.com/2011/06/jlayer-for-swing/