# CSS3 to style Java?

Tags: java, html, swing, css, javafx-2

I'm about to begin a project in Java where I'm essentially making a dumbed-down iTunes clone. I will be using Swing to make the GUI, but I was wondering the best way to style it in a way similar to iTunes beyond just changing colors/fonts/borders. I have looked into using CSS along with Java Swing, but any resources I've found are out of date. Are there any new ways to approach this? Or should I be looking into something besides CSS?

Here is the design I'm looking to implement via Swing (the basics at least):
[image]

Comment: Short of screen shots and just based on your description, I suggest looking pluggable look & feel.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added a screenshot of the design I'm looking to implement.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of LaFs for Java, and even the builtin one is skinnable. I'd recommend just picking one you like, or writing a skin if you really need the custom appearance.

Comment: I also think JavaFX uses CSS *somewhere*, but I couldn't tell you anything closer. It's probably worth investigating, especially seeing as JavaFX is the new and shiny way of doing Java UIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no CSS styling with Swing. If you use JavaFx2 however, which is the successor of Swing, you do have CSS styling available to you.

If you are not already very familiar with Swing, I suggest you consider JavaFX. The latest 1.7 versions of Java has JavaFX 2.2 built in. It has CSS support and a [Media Player](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html)

It is of course possible to also do it in Swing. There are many differnt approaches you could use, but to give you a starting point, here is how I would go about to create the buttons. This approach requires Java 7, but if you use JXLayer instead, you can also run it in previous versions of Java. The buttons are a combination of 2D paint and some icons I had access to. Just change it with icons you have. The size of the circle will resize itself, depending on the images you are using.

When you click the buttons, you will here a beep sound, and the appropriate text is printed to console. Generally speaking, JLayer is very useful for styling you Swing applications.

[image: Example of Media PLayer]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

/**
 */
public class MediaPlayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Media Clone");
                MediaController mediaController = new MediaController();
                frame.getContentPane().add(new MediaView(mediaController));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 450));
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static class MediaView extends JPanel {

        private MediaList mediaList;
        private ButtonView buttonView;
        private MediaController controller;

        MediaView(MediaController controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
            createComponents();
            makeLayout();
        }

        public void createComponents() {
            mediaList = new MediaList();
            buttonView = new ButtonView(controller);
        }

        public void makeLayout() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(mediaList);
            add(new JLayer<>(buttonView, new GradientUI()), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
    }

    static class MediaList extends JPanel {

        private JTable mediaTable;

        MediaList() {
            createComponents();
            makeLayout();
        }

        public void createComponents() {
            String[] header = new String[]{"Song", "Artist"};
            String[][] model = new String[2][2];
            model[0][0] = "Hello";
            model[0][1] = "World";
            model[1][0] = "Goodbye";
            model[1][1] = "Sunshine";
            mediaTable = new JTable(model, header);
        }

        public void makeLayout() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(mediaTable));
        }
    }

    static class GradientUI extends LayerUI<JComponent> {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            int height = c.getHeight();
            int width = c.getWidth();
            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(136, 146, 155), 0, height, new Color(101, 108, 116)));
            Rectangle2D area = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            g2.fill(area);
            super.paint(g2, c);
        }
    }

    enum MediaAction {
        PLAY, NEXT, PREVIOUS
    }

    static class MediaController {

        private Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        public void execute(MediaAction mediaAction) {
            toolkit.beep();
            System.out.println(mediaAction.name());
        }
    }

    static class ButtonView extends JPanel {

        private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ButtonView.class.getName());

        private JButton play;
        private JButton next;
        private JButton previous;
        private RoundButtonUI playUI;
        private ActionListener playActionListener;
        private ActionListener nextActionListener;
        private ActionListener previousActionListener;
        private MediaController controller;

        ButtonView(MediaController controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
            createComponents();
            makeLayout();
            createHandlers();
            registerHandlers();
            initComponent();
        }

        public void createComponents() {
            play = new JButton();
            next = new JButton();
            previous = new JButton();
            playUI = new RoundButtonUI();
        }

        public void createHandlers() {
            playActionListener = createMediaAction(MediaAction.PLAY);
            nextActionListener = createMediaAction(MediaAction.NEXT);
            previousActionListener = createMediaAction(MediaAction.PREVIOUS);
        }

        private ActionListener createMediaAction(final MediaAction mediaAction) {
            return new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            controller.execute(mediaAction);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }

        public void registerHandlers() {
            play.addActionListener(playActionListener);
            next.addActionListener(nextActionListener);
            previous.addActionListener(previousActionListener);
        }

        public void makeLayout() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
            makeButtonRound(previous, "<<", "bullet_triangle_grey_shadow.png", "bullet_triangle_grey.png");
            makeButtonRound(play, ">", "bullet_triangle_glass_grey128x128.png", "bullet_triangle_glass_grey128x128.png");
            makeButtonRound(next, ">>", "bullet_triangle_grey_shadow.png", "bullet_triangle_grey.png");
            add(new JLayer<>(previous, playUI));
            add(new JLayer<>(play, playUI));
            add(new JLayer<>(next, playUI));
        }

        public void initComponent() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        private void makeButtonRound(final JButton toBeRounded, String fallback, String imageNormal, String imagePressed) {
            toBeRounded.setOpaque(false);
            toBeRounded.setFocusPainted(false);
            toBeRounded.setBorderPainted(false);
            toBeRounded.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            toBeRounded.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 10, 5, 5));
            URL normalURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(imageNormal);
            URL pressedURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(imagePressed);
            if (normalURL != null || pressedURL != null) {
                final ImageIcon released = new ImageIcon(normalURL);
                final ImageIcon pressed = new ImageIcon(pressedURL);
                toBeRounded.setIcon(released);
                toBeRounded.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        toBeRounded.setIcon(pressed);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        toBeRounded.setIcon(released);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                toBeRounded.setText(fallback);
                log.severe("Missing resources: " + imageNormal + " and " + imagePressed);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shifts the image so it looks pressed down.
     * Creates a circle around the icon, that varies in size depending on the supplied icon.
     */
    static class RoundButtonUI extends LayerUI<JComponent> {

        private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 5;

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            ButtonModel buttonModel;
            JButton b;

            if (((JLayer) c).getView() instanceof JButton) {
                b = (JButton) ((JLayer) c).getView();
                buttonModel = b.getModel();
            } else {
                super.paint(g, c);
                return;
            }

            int iconHeight = b.getIcon() != null ? b.getIcon().getIconHeight() : 60;
            int iconWidth = b.getIcon() != null ? b.getIcon().getIconWidth() : 60;

            Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(STROKE_WIDTH, STROKE_WIDTH, iconHeight, iconWidth);

            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(5, 5, new Color(222, 224, 230), 30, 55, new Color(187, 189, 199)));
            g2.fill(circle);

            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(15, 0, new Color(90, 97, 105), 15, 30, new Color(132, 142, 152)));
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            g2.draw(circle);

            if (buttonModel.isPressed()) {
                g2.translate(1, 1);
            }

            super.paint(g2, c);
            g2.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking more into JavaFX, it may be just what I'm looking for. I'm installing it now and I'll have to do some more research. Thanks!

Comment: @MadProgrammer is right in flagging that my "successor of Swing"-statement could turn out to be wrong, but at least that is the prediction of the Oracle on the Q6 "Is JavaFX replacing Swing..?" Res "Yes. However, Swing will remain...". See [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6). JavaFX version 1 was a script language, and as such did not appeal to a wide user base of existing Swing programmers, myself included. JavaFX 2+ has a much better chance of succeeding in my opinion since it is becoming an integral part of Java.

Comment: @Skjalg Not saying it's a bad technology, it's just another choice ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer It is, so I added an example using Swing.

Answer (score 2):

Building the look you desire with swing would be a real challenge. It can be done, but not with CSS, and not without considerable work. Since JavaFX supports CSS and has a media player, I would look into this new framework instead. You can [get started here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/)

I recently built a small JavaFX application and I had the chance to play with scene builder, the graphical tool that now integrates with Netbeans to assist the developer in creating the UI. As you modify the CSS file, the UI is updated in scene builder. The actual elements that we style are different than the ones we use with HTML. Below is the CSS file I used for my application; you can view & run my application at [mathteamhosting.com](http://mathteamhosting.com/teachers/javaFX/ProbabilityGame.html)

Keep in mind that if you are using a 32 bit browser, you need a 32 bit version of Java to run this as an applet.

```
.root { 
    display: block;
}

.text-input {
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.text-field {
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.label {
    -fx-font-size: 18px;   
}

.button {
    -fx-font-size: 15px;   
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#0000ff, #ffeeff);
}
#note {
    -fx-font-size: 15px;  
}

#heading {
    -fx-text-fill: #000099;
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```